# How do I make Android Studio always open search results in the "find window"?

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-2.4

Lately, Android Studio started opening search results (Ctrl + Shift + F) in a intermediate window like this:

[image]
Is there any way I can have it open search result in the "Find Window" automatically instead of having to press `Ctrl + Enter` ?

I'm using Android Studio 2.4 Preview 6

Comment: you solve this issue yet? I guess there's setting hiding somewhere

Comment: still no luck :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in the menu Help>>edit custom VM options , set the following

> -Dide.find.as.popup=false